# How to restart nginx on OS X

Tags: macos, nginx, restart

I'm using `nginx` on OS X 10.8. Freshly installed `nginx` but can't find a way to restart nginx except `kill nginx_pid` say `kill 64116`. Wondering if there are better ways to restart `nginx`.

Found some methods on Google and SO but didn't work:

```
nginx -s restart

sudo fuser -k 80/tcp ; sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

The error message for `nginx -s restart` is

```
nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Sometimes also get this error msg:

```
nginx: invalid option: "-s restart"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What is your nginx pid file location? This is specified in the configuration file, default paths specified compile-time in the config script. You can search for it as such:

`find / -name nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` (must issue while nginx is running)

Solution:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/run/
ln -s /current/path/to/pid/file /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid
```

Comment: By running the above `find` command I found `/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` does exist. The error msg now is `nginx: invalid option: "-s restart"`

Comment: That's because it's not a valid signal. Check the `man` page (which you should always do, anyway): `Send signal to a master process: stop, quit, reopen, reload.`

Comment: It seems a better way to simulate restart is `nginx -s stop; nginx`

Comment: or `nginx -s reload` if you just need updating config

Comment: If youre looking for where `nginx` is, [according to the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) its on one of three places, ***By default, the configuration file is named nginx.conf and placed in the directory `/usr/local/nginx/conf`, `/etc/nginx`, or `/usr/local/etc/nginx`.*** I found mine in `/etc/nginx`

Comment: After doing this this I ran `sudo nginx -s reload` and got the error: `nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (62: Too many levels of symbolic links)`

Comment: @allieferr if you run `file /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` you'll see that it is a symbolic link to another location (perhaps a package manager's installation directory). Run `sudo rm /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid; sudo touch /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` to fix that. Unless the problem is that an ancestor in that path is a symlink, in which case you'll have to do some digging.

Comment: The nginx.pid file is really in the correct location, /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid, and I am sure I send the valid signal, but I still get the same error: nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 111):

Try running `sudo nginx` before starting nginx.

Comment: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()

Comment: @pinouchon i get the above. i want to stop and restart

Answer (score 34):

To reload config files:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

To fully restart `nginx`:

```
sudo nginx -s quit
sudo nginx
```

---

**Details**

There is no `restart` signal for nginx. From the docs, here are the signals that the master process accepts:

```
SIGINT, SIGTERM  Shut down quickly.
SIGHUP           Reload configuration, start the new worker process with a new configuration, and gracefully shut down old worker processes.
SIGQUIT          Shut down gracefully.
SIGUSR1          Reopen log files.
SIGUSR2          Upgrade the nginx executable on the fly.
SIGWINCH         Shut down worker processes gracefully.
```

Presumably you could send these signals to the process id manually, but the `nginx` command has the flag `nginx -s <signal>` that sends signals to the master process for you. Your options are:

```
stop    SIGTERM
quit    SIGQUIT
reopen  SIGUSR1
reload  SIGHUP
```

No need to futz with the pid manually.

---

*Edit:* just realized much of this info was already in comments on the other answers. Leaving this here anyway to summarize the situation.

Comment: i get this sudo nginx -s reload
nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: This was helpful by proxy: 'nginx' by itself got my service running.  I had assumed it'd start automatically as so many do.  I had the exact same error as previous comment before I did this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

`sudo nginx -s stop`

followed by a:

`sudo nginx`

It seems that nginx keeps track of its state, to if you stop it twice, it will complain. But the above worked for me.

Comment: Ironically `sudo nginx` fixes the issue. after that I was able to reload and run the server without any errors.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ sudo nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

Source Link: https://blog.csdn.net/github_33644920/article/details/51733436

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I do it like this:

First kill the progress

```
ps aux | grep nginx
kill -9 {pid}
```

Then start nginx

```
nginx
```

It works!

Comment: This method doesn't work for me! I want to know what the meaning of 9?

Answer (score 3):

As a future resource, you can consult http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine

`Nginx` probably runs as root, so you will need to run a variant of the following command to affect it.

```
sudo nginx -s stop | reload | quit | reopen
```

There is usually not much reason to restart `Nginx` like `Apache` would need. If you have modified a configuration file, you may just want to the reload option.

Comment: nginx: [error] invalid PID number "" in "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" ...

Answer (score 2):

check if this directory exists:

```
/usr/local/var/run
```

this error can occurs when nginx try to initialise pid file in 
localisation that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug here.   Depending on whether nginx is running while you modify/restart apache and/or modify nginx configs it is possible for this file (which is essentially just a process ID pointer) to  be destroyed.

When you attempt to send any signal to nginx like

```
nginx -s quit;
nginx -s stop;
nginx -s reload;
```

nginx uses this file to reference the ID of the process to which it needs to send the signal.  If the file isn't there the link between the active running process of nginx & the cli app is effectively broken.

I actually ended up in a state where two nginx processes were running simultaneously so killed both.

To work around this, you can either Force the termination of existing nginx processes via Activity Monitor (then run nginx & have the cli app create a new nginx.pid file) or if you REALLY need to keep nginx running but want to run nginx -s reload - manually create a file in the /run path called nginx.pid and insert the PID of the currently running nginx processs (obtained via Activity Monitor).

Comment: Would be helpful to show the code on how to kill those processes via command line.

Answer (score 1):

To reload the custom config file use

```
nginx -s reload -c /etc/nginx/conf.d/<config file>.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

This could simply mean that nginx is already stopped - not running at the moment.
First, confirm whether nginx is running, execute:

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error link you, i tried many way to fix it but it not working
after that i run the command line and it work well:
nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

the information i got from here
https://blog.csdn.net/wn1245343496/article/details/77974756

Comment: This is a better solution than leaving symlinks behind in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

One way to stop or reload is through the below command,

For stop:

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop
```

Run reload only if the nginx is running:

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

By doing like the above, you wont get nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" this issue