# can't start nginx in osx

Tags: macos, nginx

I've just started with `nginx` in a `MacOS Sierra v10.12.1`.

After installed with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_es.html), the browser refuses me to connect with the message: `This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.`

I've just then try to debug my nginx with `nginx -t` and it says that `nginx.pid` is missing:

```
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

in addition, if I try to `reload`, it throws the following error:

`nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Any idea of what's going on?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like Nginx has not started. Run below command (Correct the path based on your nginx daemon). It should be either

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

or

```
sudo /usr/local/etc/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

Also find out the correct location of nginx.pid with below command

```
find / -name nginx.pid 2>/dev/null
```

Then update the path in your conf and then reload again using the first command.

Comment: it seems that there's no sbin in my `/usr/local/nginx/` folder. About the `nginx.pid`, it finds it in the path `/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` but if I `ls -la`, it throws me this result: ` 25 Nov  8 17:21 nginx.pid -> /current/path/to/pid/file`
`

Comment: It seems like installation issue. Can you run below command to find out if nginx sbin exisits on system on any path.

Comment: find / -name sbin 2>/dev/null

Comment: the response I get is: `/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin`

Comment: I found a similar discussion in detail for nginx on os x. Check this out if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176477/how-to-restart-nginx-on-os-x

Comment: after following that other thread, I keep having issues, but referenced to this other error now: `nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (62: Too many levels of symbolic links)`. When I `find / -name nginx.pid 2>/dev/null`, it points to `/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127671/discussion-between-devstarlight-and-umar-hayat).